# Is it normal to pass out after over exerting oneself?

Tags: fatigue

I'm 57 here's my deal, let's say a block long quick sprint. At the end of that sprint, can't catch my breath, tunnel vision, pass out, wake up on the sidewalk. Any clues?

Comment: that sounds like a heart problem. you should see a doctor

Comment: Or other things, some severe, some less so. But either way it's a medical issue that needs professional attention. Until then I will add one gentle suggestion - don't push yourself that hard. Apart from the medical aspects, there's a fine line between passing out ending up on the sidewalk, and passing out ending up in the road getting run over

Comment: Dude... Wut?? **DOCTOR**

Answer (score 9):

The only advice that can be given here:

*Don't look for internet advice, consult a doctor.*

Answer (score 7):

You need to consult a doctor, in person.

This question will be closed as "health advice is offtopic" because SE won't take the liability.   Please don't take it personally, but do see a doctor.